# Is there a difference between ‘ammonium hydroxide’ and ‘aqueous ammonia’?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution

Water ($\ce{H2O}$) can be added to ammonia ($\ce{NH3}$) in order to form ammonium hydroxide ($\ce{NH4OH}$):
$$\ce{NH3 + H2O -> NH4OH}$$

But we know that ammonia is gaseous at STP so writing $\ce{NH3 + H2O}$ equals writing $\ce{NH3(aq)}$ right?

If yes, then the equation will look like:
$$\ce{NH3(aq) -> NH4OH}$$

So my question is: is **ammonium hydroxide $\ce{NH4OH}$** simply **aqueous ammonia $\ce{NH3(aq)}$?** Or am I missing something?
Can I resume the first equation like this?
$$\ce{NH3(g) + H2O(l) -> NH3(aq)}$$

Comment: Yes that is the gist of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_hydroxide In pure water NH3 is like CO2. The most prevalent species is the dissolved gas, not the ionic forms.

Comment: That's right. Aqueous ammonia contains a little bit of ammonium hydroxide. Pure ammonium hydroxide doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Very related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48373/ammonium-hydroxide-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ammonia is a weak base, ammonium is a weak acid. Water is a very weak acid and hydroxide is a very strong base. Taken together, this tells us that equilibrium $(1)$ is pushed towards the reactant side.

$$\ce{NH3 (aq) + H2O (l) <<=> NH4+ (aq) + OH- (aq)}\tag{1}$$

Thus, it is practically impossible to form stoichiometric ammonium hydroxide; the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values tell us that ammonium ions and hydroxide ions put together will generate water and ammonia.

However, it is also true that equation $(1)$ is an *equilibrium* — everybody has seen a solution of ammonia in water display basic properties so hydroxide ions (and thus ammonium ions) are unquestionably *there.* The predominant species is dissolved ammonia, though.

$$\ce{NH3 (g) + H2O (l) <=>> NH3 (aq) + H2O (l)}\tag{2}$$

It is correct that the most important process when dissolving ammonia in water is $(2)$ — $(1)$ plays a more minor role. Thus, it is also more correct to speak of *solutions of ammonia* — but at the same time *ammonium hydroxide* is commonly understood even if not formally correct.

By the way beware: occasionally students are sent off to fetch ‘solid ammonium hydroxide’ as a joke — similar to students getting sent off to fetch ‘vacuum gas’, ‘three phenol rings’ etc.