# How to predict which complex is formed and which are soluble?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, coordination-compounds

[image]

How does one come to know (in this table) which metal cations form ammonia complexes and which ones form hydroxy complexes on reaction with $\ce{NH4OH}$

**Reference**:

1. *J.D Lee - Concise Inorganic Chemistry* by Sudarshan Guha

Comment: You can't really know specific properties without experimentation, also you can make rules and generalisations for similar behaivour. I think a good starting point would be the Wikipedia article for the 'HSAB theory'. It mainly fulfills your need for the complex formation prediction. The theory even assigns values for acids and bases based on the valence state, ionisation energy and electron affinity called hardness.

Comment: Can you please illustrate an example of this using HSAB principle as this has been extremely confusing

Comment: You may need more time to understand the topic, assuming it is new to you. There is a picture of the periodic table (f block elements excluded) on the mentioned article found at the Theory paragraph. The picture associates strenght with color, and the bonds tend do be more stable when hard and hard or soft and soft are pairing. As your source states Zn and Cd do form amine complexes, while Al doesnt.

Comment: Al is considered a hard acid while Zn is intermediate, Cd is soft. O donors are somewhat harder bases than N so based on the aforementioned assumption the softer Zn and Cd pair better with the softer N donor while Al pairs better with the harder O donor.

Comment: I have come across HSAB principle before particularly in the context of conjugate addition.However it is a bit new for me to apply this in inorganic chemistry but I think I get the idea. How would you apply this for determining solubility ?

Comment: Predicting solubility reliable would be surely a Nobel-prize canidate, as for now it is mostly impossible to calculate it. The Wikipedia article mentions that generally soft-soft interactions are more covalent wich tend to be insoluble in water, while hard-hard bonds have ionic character that are expected to be soluble in water. While this is a nice statement we immediately face an exception namely Al(OH)3 wich is a hard-hard interaction between Al3+ and OH-, is insoluble in water and has a covalent nature. Overall there are rules you can apply, but there will be always exceptions.

Comment: What can be done to make this question better?

Answer (score 3):

Please be mindful, in my opinion, that your source material may not be of the highest quality.

For example, NH4OH is more accurately represented as aqueous ammonia (that is, NH3(aq), see, for example, [this source's comment](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed066p310)).

Second, Al(OH)3 does not form a complex with ammonia or, as your reference claims, is 'partially soluble' with aqueous ammonia to any significant extent, and if at all, likely due to the presence of OH-. See, for example, this ebook, [Basic Analytical Chemistry](https://books.google.com/books?id=QjoXBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=is+Al(OH)3+partially+soluble+in+aqueous+ammonia&source=bl&ots=xuTUFWtlBw&sig=ACfU3U3p0eHZPo9vvqbvFWYyTj4xSqYvZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAso-bgo_qAhUpSN8KHcK2BzAQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=is%20Al(OH)3%20partially%20soluble%20in%20aqueous%20ammonia&f=false)
 discussing various metal compounds interactions with aqueous ammonia.

Third, a more accurate depiction of the action of ammonia on Cu(OH)2, for example, is the formation of a complex of the form, $\ce{[Cu(NH3)_x(H2O)y](+)}$, where x + y = 6, with also a possible charge of 2+ for cupric, where the concentration of ammonia influences the value of 'x' (supplying guidance on your question as to which possible complex may form).

Lastly, high strength ammonia is needed to react with some of the listed metal hydroxides and is characteristic of the particular metal. See my suggested source, that may address your question on which salts are (or, are not) soluble.

Comment: Do you have another link for "Ammonium hydroxide doesn't exist"? The one above requires to be purchased.

Comment: @B.Anshuman These previous chem.SE questions([here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69555/is-there-a-difference-between-ammonium-hydroxide-and-aqueous-ammonia) and [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48373/ammonium-hydroxide-name)) will be of help.