# Are these two reactions the same?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution

I read the book an it said when $\ce{NH4Cl}$ dissolves in the water, the reaction  of $\ce{NH4+}$ will be

$$\ce{NH4+ <=> NH3 + H+},$$

but instead, the first reaction came to my mind was

$$\ce{NH4+ + H2O <=> NH4OH + H+}$$

Are these two reaction the same? And if they are the same, does that means that $\ce{NH3} = \ce{NH4OH}$ in the water?

Comment: I'd say NH4OH is not much of a thing. You may assume it is always fully dissociated. But some (maybe a major part) of NH3 exists as just NH3.

Comment: Thanks guys. Forgive my foolishness.