# Dilution formula for NH3 solution

Tags: concentration

I need this for an experiment:
ca. 3 mL concentrated (15 M) aqueous ammonia solution, NH3 (from a dropping bottle.)

I have the NH4OH pictured below. How can I dilute it to get what I need? What is the formula?

[image: Ammonia Water]

Comment: The label is a shame, I would not buy products from such a company for serious lab work.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with a mass fraction of $25\ \%$ ammonia corresponds to a concentration of $c_1=13.32\ \mathrm{mol\ l^{-1}}$. So obviously you cannot dilute this solution to reach a higher concentration of $c_2=15\ \mathrm{mol\ l^{-1}}$, which corresponds to a mass fraction of $28.5\ \%$.

Depending on the experiment, however, you could simply use more of the available solution according to
$$\begin{align}n_1&=n_2\\[3pt]
c_1V_1&=c_2V_2\\[3pt]
V_1&=\frac{c_2V_2}{c_1}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{15\ \mathrm{mol\ l^{-1}}\times 3\ \mathrm{ml}}{13.32\ \mathrm{mol\ l^{-1}}}\\[3pt]
&=3.4\ \mathrm{ml}\end{align}$$

Also note that the fictitious substance “ammonium hydroxide” $(\ce{NH4OH})$ with a molar mass of $35.05\ \mathrm{g\ mol^{-1}}$ (as shown on the label) [does not exist.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/48407/103369)

Comment: Makes sense, but can you please show me how you got 13.32 mol l−1?