# NH4+ reaction with NaOH

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why does $NH4^+$ react with NaOH to give $NH_3+H_2O$ and not $NH_4OH$

Comment: Because there is no $\ce{NH4OH}$, except as the separate solvated ions which are minor species in an aqueous ammonia solution.  See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/123839/17175) for the whole story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ce{NH4+}$ is the weak acid and reacts with the strong base $\ce{OH-}$:

$$\ce{NH4+ + OH- <=>> NH3 + H2O}$$

by the same way as $\ce{HCN}$, an acid with similar acidity as $\ce{NH4+}$:

$$\ce{HCN + OH- <=>> CN- + H2O}$$